# Storing platform used in php

Tags: php, function, platform

I created this function with hopes of being able to retrieve platform used to take a web survey. However it's just returning desktop for everything! (even iPhone, etc). Can anyone help please?

Comment: Why do you keep trying to edit out the content of the question?? Before a question is answered, you can delete it. After it has been answered, it belongs to the community, and being the original poster doesn't give you the privilege to turn it into an invalid question and leave the answer(s) without context.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple script - [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) .It's easy to use:

```
<?php
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {

}
```

It's better, because this script cover more cases to detect mobile devices.

Comment: so the mobile device info would be stored in $detect?

Comment: Yes. I think in $detect are info about user agent and HTTP headers. This script uses regex to find correctly device.